# JavaFx adding a text label on top of StackedBarChart

Tags: javafx-2

**After Search**

- I found this sample [how to display bar value on top of bar javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237192/how-to-display-bar-value-on-top-of-bar-javafx/15375168?noredirect=1#comment25959299_15375168), But that when bar separated on the category axis so each `category data has a single bar` and Listener can be added to that data (Category).
- But with `StackedBarChart` each category consists of StackedBar.
- I try that **[code simple](https://gist.github.com/KhaledLela/6071422)** based on the @jewelsea code.
- That solution work prefect if all series are symmetric and contain all the categories. 
  [image: symmetric Series]
- **But** with non-symmetric series

  ```
      ObservableList<StackedBarChart.Series> barChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
          new StackedBarChart.Series("Region 1", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
          new StackedBarChart.Data(years[0], 567d),
          new StackedBarChart.Data(years[1], 1292d),
          new StackedBarChart.Data(years[2], 1292d))),
          new StackedBarChart.Series("Region 2", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
          new StackedBarChart.Data(years[0], 956),
          new StackedBarChart.Data(years[1], 1665),
          new StackedBarChart.Data(years[2], 2559))),
          new StackedBarChart.Series("Region 3", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
          new StackedBarChart.Data(years[0], 1154),
          //new StackedBarChart.Data(years[1], 1927),// series names Region 3(which is the last series on the chart data) doesn't exist category years[1] "2008".
          new StackedBarChart.Data(years[2], 2774))));
  ```
- **We will miss Text on top of category 2008**.
  [image: non-symmetric series miss text on the missing categories]
- Any help are welcome.

Comment: @jewelsea this me solution .

Comment: Did you suceed to update data AND bar values on top of bars ? Or at least remove bar values on top of bars

Comment: @JérémyHalin Please check this code. [gist](https://gist.github.com/KhaledLela)

Comment: I did and commented one of your gist, please see :)

Answer (score 0):

It's missing because you comment it out:

```
    //new StackedBarChart.Data(years[1], 1927),// series names Region 3(which is the last series on the chart data) doesn't exist category years[1] "2008".
```

That second parameter is the "1927" title.  This is technically the Y-Axis parameter.  You need to keep that line in order to show that "1927".  Check out the API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/StackedBarChart.html

You may need to put your "titles" up another way.  Use a text class and add it on top of the StackedBarChart.Series objects.

Comment: I exactly want to comment that line as a case of the last series didn't contain all the categories .

Comment: Try setLegendVisible() on the new StackedBarChart.Data(years[1], 1665) part?

Comment: I got the method from here (StackedBarChart uses both Data and Series):  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/Chart.html#setLegendVisible%28boolean%29