# Label on Bar Chart stays on value refreshed

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, bar-chart

I went through the question

[how to display bar value on top of bar javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237192/how-to-display-bar-value-on-top-of-bar-javafx/15375168)

I tried the same code with `data refresh`. The text seems to stay, once the data is refreshed. I tried to `remove the text once added`, but received no success as there is no way to get through the parent before `XYSeries` object is populated !

If you go through the following link, I have modified the code and kept a `refresh button` at the bottom. On pressing it, the `chart gets new values, but the old Text stays`. Is there a way to remove it, before new values are supplied to the chart

http://gist.github.com/abhinayagarwal/9474756

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ? I'm having the same issue.