# javafx implement x-value labels for a line chart

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I tried to implement the method of jewelsea according to this post [label on barchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237192/how-to-display-bar-value-on-top-of-bar-javafx) but labels are not visible and i don't understand why.
The only difference is I use an fxml file and my chart data are composed of several series.

To illustrate better the problem, I made a MVCE of the situation :

```js
public class PaneController implements Initializable{
 @FXML
 private LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart;

 @Override
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);
  lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
  lineChart.setData(createData());
  
  /** for each serie add label on the peak if intensity > 0 */
  for(int i=0;i<lineChart.getData().size();i++){
   for(XYChart.Data<Number, Number> value:lineChart.getData().get(i).getData()){
    if(value.getYValue().intValue()>0){
       value.nodeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>() {
              @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> ov, Node oldNode, final Node node) {
               System.out.println("value:"+node);
                  if (node != null) {
                    displayLabelForData(value);
                  } 
                }
              });
    }
      }
  }
  
 }
 /** create data for the line chart */
 public ObservableList<Series<Number,Number>> createData(){
   ObservableList<Series<Number,Number>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> peakSelect = new XYChart.Series<>();
    peakSelect.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(i,0));
    peakSelect.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(i,i*2));
    data.add(peakSelect);
   }
   return data;
 }
 
   /** places a x value label on each peak */
   private void displayLabelForData(XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data){
    final Node node = data.getNode();
    final Text dataText = new Text(data.getXValue() + "");
    node.parentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Parent>() {
     @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Parent> ov, Parent oldParent, Parent parent) {
      Group parentGroup = (Group) parent;
      parentGroup.getChildren().add(dataText);
     }
    });
    
    node.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
     @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> ov, Bounds oldBounds, Bounds bounds) {
      
      dataText.setLayoutX( Math.round( bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2 - dataText.prefWidth(-1) / 2 ) );
      dataText.setLayoutY( Math.round( bounds.getMinY() - dataText.prefHeight(-1) * 0.5 ) );
     }
    });
   }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.PaneController">
   <children>
      <LineChart fx:id="lineChart" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <xAxis>
          <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
      </LineChart>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Main Class:

```js
public class Main extends Application {
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  try {
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
   loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Pane.fxml"));
   AnchorPane rootPane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
   Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
   primaryStage.show();
   
   PaneController controller = loader.getController();
            
  } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
 }
}
```

Thank you for any help !

Comment: The problem lies in the `initialize` method at the `value.nodeProperty().addListener` line. Somehow the `ChangeListener` is never called. I'll see if I can find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to fix your problem, however I can point you to another way to get a similar effect. If you need to use a line chart you could try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623439/4683264. However from your sample it looks like you could use a barchart, and use jewelsea's answer from the question you linked.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I noticed the listener is not used but i don't understand why. I think the problem is not the type of chart but the use of an fxml file. I tried the code of jewelsea with a line chart and it works.

Comment: @Thomas The view node is null the whole time, it is never set... Anyway glad I could help.