# refresh value of a Label on Bar Chart javafx

Tags: javafx

I tried to display value of a bar chart on top of each one using the code posted on [how to display bar value on top of bar javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237192/how-to-display-bar-value-on-top-of-bar-javafx/15375168), but when i update serie's values , the old value stays showing in the bar chart :( .
can you help me :) .
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the label to the series value.

ex.
`xAxis.setLabel(series1.toString());`

Hopefully that helps