# Adding values on top of each on a realtime javafx bar chart

Tags: java, javafx, charts

I'm new in Java and I'm trying to create a reatime javaFX bar chart which shows updating values on top of each bar.
I got this Bar chart which is updated every second. How can I add values on top of each bar using this chart. There are other examples online but there are not compatible with the real time bar chart on this code. How can I also add text inside a each bar. Thanks

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class App extends Application {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    final static String austria = "Austria";
    final static String brazil = "Brazil";
    final static String france = "France";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Realtime Bar Chart Demo");

        //defining the axes
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        xAxis.setAnimated(false);
        yAxis.setAnimated(false);

        //creating the bar chart with two axis
        final BarChart<String,Number> bc =  new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
        bc.setAnimated(false);
        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        //defining a series to display data
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesA = new XYChart.Series<>();
        seriesA.setName("Austra");

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesB = new XYChart.Series<>();
        seriesB.setName("Brazil");

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesC = new XYChart.Series<>();
        seriesC.setName("France");

        // add series to chart
        bc.getData().add(seriesA);
        bc.getData().add(seriesB);
        bc.getData().add(seriesC);

        // setup scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(bc, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // show the stage
        primaryStage.show();

        // setup a scheduled executor to periodically put data into the chart
        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        // input data onto graph per second
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            int secondA = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            int secondB = secondA + 27;
            int secondC = secondA + 14;

            // Update the chart
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                // input realtime data number
                seriesA.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(austria, secondA));
                seriesB.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(brazil, secondB));
                seriesC.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(france, secondC));
            });
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        scheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post [mre]. The posted code does not compile.

Comment: I updated the code, it should compile now.

Comment: Did you test it ? Does `Austria` compile ?  does `Calendar.SECONDS` compile ?   You're asking people here to volunteer to solve your problem, and you should make it as easy as possible for them to do so.

Comment: On my computer it was compiling and data updating. I made a copy to my phone because I won't be at home for a while. Do I have to include imports also?

Comment: Yes. Imports and formatting are important. Are you trying to show the values of each bar at the top ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to show values on top of each bar using realtime chart

Comment: hmm .. don't see any code for  _shows updating values on top of each bar_ -  do it statically (or on a button click), then go furher to do it from a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an mre implementing some changes in your code and using the solution proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15375168/3992939):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    final static String austria = "Austria",  brazil = "Brazil",  france = "France";
    private IntegerProperty secondA,  secondB , secondC; 
    private Text secondAText, secondBText , secondCText;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Realtime Bar Chart Demo");

        //defining the axes
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        xAxis.setAnimated(false);
        yAxis.setAnimated(false);

        //creating the bar chart with two axis
        final BarChart<String,Number> bc =  new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
        bc.setAnimated(false);
        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        //defining a series to display data
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesA = new XYChart.Series<>();
        Data<String, Number> dataA = new XYChart.Data<>(austria,0);
        seriesA.getData().add(dataA);
        seriesA.setName("Austra");

        secondA = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        secondAText = new Text("");
        secondA.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            dataA.setYValue(newValue);
            secondAText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
        });

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesB = new XYChart.Series<>();
        Data<String, Number> dataB = new XYChart.Data<>(brazil,0);
        seriesB.getData().add(dataB);
        seriesB.setName("Brazil");
        secondB =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        secondB.bind(secondA.add(27));
        secondBText = new Text("");
        secondB.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            dataB.setYValue(newValue);
            secondBText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
        });

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesC = new XYChart.Series<>();
        Data<String, Number> dataC = new XYChart.Data<>(france,0);
        seriesC.getData().add(dataC);
        seriesC.setName("France");

        secondC =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        secondC.bind(secondA.add(14));
        secondCText = new Text("");
        secondC.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            dataC.setYValue(newValue);
            secondCText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
        });

        // add series to chart
        bc.getData().add(seriesA);
        bc.getData().add(seriesB);
        bc.getData().add(seriesC);

        displayLabelForData(dataA, secondAText);
        displayLabelForData(dataB, secondBText);
        displayLabelForData(dataC, secondCText);

        // setup scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(bc, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // show the stage
        primaryStage.show();

        // setup a scheduled executor to periodically put data into the chart
        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        // input data onto graph per second
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

            // Update the chart
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                secondA.set( cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            });
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        scheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow();
    }

    private void displayLabelForData(XYChart.Data<String, Number> data, Text text) {

        final Node node = data.getNode();
        ((Group) node.getParent()).getChildren().add(text);

        node.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Bounds>) (ov, oldBounds, bounds) -> {
            text.setLayoutX(
                    Math.round( bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2 - text.prefWidth(-1) / 2));
            text.setLayoutY(Math.round( bounds.getMinY() - text.prefHeight(-1) * 0.5));
        });
    }
}
```

Side note: You could use javafx tools to run the periodic task:

```
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            Duration.seconds(1),
            e -> {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                secondA.set( cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            }
     ));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
```

---

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to use this method to turn the bar chart horizontal xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90); but it doesn't work. What is a problem then?

Comment: a.`doesn't work.` is not a good problem description b. for horizontal needs different layout calculation c. If you need help with horizontal  post a new question.

Comment: @kleopatra I don't know if it is homework or not. I don't find it important. Anyhow I don't know much, but most of what I did learn was from examples. When I start to learn a new subject I need examples which are very close to my use case.(**"**_There are other examples online but there are not compatible with the real time bar chart on this code_**"**, the OP). I try to help others in the same way I want to get help.

Comment: Also my view is that duplicate answered questions are not necessarily bad.  I am not the first one to express this view of course
**"**_some duplication is desirable. There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds people can find the answer they’re looking for_**"** [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: well, here the asker didn't try _anything_ to get near her/his goal (in the question code, there is no trace at all of the statement _other examples online but there are not compatible with the real time bar chart_). Given her/his comment to this answer, it looks very much like nothing learned :) Would be glad to be wrong, though, we'll see in the follow-up question

Comment: @kleopatra no effort indeed in the followup question. I did not think the code in this question was copy-pasted from somewhere. Anyway _`You can lead a horse to water but you can't make him drink'_